# Get selected fields from an multiple array object lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have an object like

```
var data = [
    {
        "inputDate":"2017-11-25T00:00:00.000Z",
        "billingCycle":6,
        "total":1
    },{
        "inputDate":"2017-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "billingCycle":1,"total":1
    }
]
```

I need to get the result like

```
var result = [
    {
        "billingCycle":6,
        "total":1
    },{
        "billingCycle":1,
        "total":1
    }
]
```

tried with

```
_.map(data, a => _.omit(a, 'inputDate'))
```

but not I'm not able to achieve the actual result. Please help me on this.

Comment: This works in browser, but since you've tagged node.js...problem is related to environment, i guess...

Comment: I think it's rather unlikely that such a simple transformation of an array of plain objects would fail because of being in a certain environment.

Are you sure that you're giving lodash an actual array of objects, instead of, for example, a JSON string?

Comment: @Jeffrey Westerkamp I was passing a callback result from a mysql  table query using sequelize.

Comment: @Jeffrey Westerkamp achieved the result by doing JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)).

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `data` into the lodash's `map` function.

`_.map(data, a => _.omit(a, 'inputDate'))`

The result:

`[ { billingCycle: 6, total: 1 }, { billingCycle: 1, total: 1 } ]`

Comment: Sorry @Abhyudit Jain it's a typo error.Actually i tried with data only.

Comment: @KarthikMannava it's working on mine. Can you edit the post with exact steps and code?

Comment: Actually the actual data was a callback result from mysql table. I achieved it by doing the callback result with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).